# Counting number of posts with Category B in Category A

Tags: wp-query, categories, custom-taxonomy, multi-taxonomy-query

I'm currently building my own backlog tracker and have gotten to a point where I just have no idea how I'm going to do this.

I have multiple status categories (for example; beaten and completed) and categories for the consoles (for example PS4 and Nintendo Switch). Now I want to display how many games(posts) I have beaten (Category A) for the Nintendo Switch (Category B)

For Example; I have 66 games, 34 from those are from the Nintendo Switch.
From those 34 Switch games, I have actually beaten 24. I want to display this "24".

can anyone give me an idea of where to go and how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Make use of the [`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) class, namely the [`tax_query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters) and `fields` parameters. Get the count from the `$found_posts` property. Please note, this is exemplary code.

```
$query = new WP_Query( [
  'post_type' => 'games',
  'tax_query' = [
    'relation' => 'AND',
    [
      'taxonomy' => 'game_status',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => [ 'beaten' ],
    ],
    [
      'taxonomy' => 'console',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => [ 'switch' ],
    ]
  ],
  'fields' => 'ids',
] );

$count = $query->found_posts;
```

Comment: Note: You probably want to set `posts_per_page => -1` so that it returns all posts. If I read your query right, it's going to return whatever the default `posts_per_page` value each time because it assumes the presence of paging. Maybe this isn't the case for CPT?

Comment: @Nicolai no, you don’t want to set it to -1. You don’t have to get all the posts (what if there are millions of posts?). There is 'found_posts' field in WP_Query object that is filled for pagination purposes - you can use it instead of counting results yourself. This way you can retrieve only one row from DB.

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż You're right, much better.